# Loading a nested repeater with Data from 2 Entity Framework Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have 2 tables A and B that have a many to many relationship.  I am using nested repeaters to show the data in a web page.  My issue is, how do I write an ObjectQuery or an IQueryable query that returns the parent rows in A and the child rows in B so that I can use them as my data sources for my inner and out repeater.  I have the code I wrote so far below but I am not sure if it is correct or even close.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="A" runat="server"><br/>
    <ItemTemplate><br/>
        <h2 class="Information"><br/>
            <%# Eval("Name") %> (<%#Eval("Abbreviation")%>)<br/>
        </h2><br/>
        <hr/><br/>
        <p> <%# Eval("Description")%> </p><br/>
        <asp:Repeater ID="B" runat="server"><br/>
            <ItemTemplate><br/>
                <li><br/>
                    <a href="..Pages/Category.aspx?<%# Eval("ID") %>"><br/>
                        <%# Eval("Name") %><br/>
                    </a><br/>
                </li>                        <br/>
            </ItemTemplate><br/>
        </asp:Repeater><br/>
    </ItemTemplate><br/>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is my C# codebehind so far:

```
        using (DBEntities connection = new DBEntities())
        {


            ObjectQuery<A> As = connection.A;
            IQueryable<A> aQuery = from a in As
                                               orderby a.SortOrder
                                               select a;


            TechnologyRepeater.DataSource = As;
            DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "What is the best way to do this with combining the data into the entity framework?" Do you have the association in your model? If not, why not?

Comment: My model was a bit confusing because of how I had my many-to-many join. I fixed the issue and now the many-to-many is showing up without the joining table like it should.  I then did what Brian said entering <asp:Repeater ... DataSource="<% Eval("B") %>">.  Do I need do something in my IQueryable or add another IQuerable for B to get the data?  I don't know how I would do an <asp:Repeater ... DataSource="<% Eval("Bs") %>"> as Bs doesn't exist in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many to many is setup different ways depending on structure.  If class A has a collection of B entities, you can bind it directly to the DataSource property as in:

```
<asp:Repeater ... DataSource="<% Eval("Bs") %>">
```

So it depends on how the entities are referenced in your object model, which again varies depending on the many to many setup.  Check this out: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/inserting-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-with-or-without-a-join-entity/